# Proper material for a drilling master plate

Tags: print-material

I've developed a master plate for my hobby woodwork (approx. 40x40x40 mm, see the figure). Its goal is to allow a straight angle while drilling 40 mm parallel bars. Four vertical holes are used to fix a 6 mm drilling bit in the perpendicular position. I use a low-power screw gun for drilling.

I ordered this part and I am mostly happy with the result, but I think I've failed to choose the right material for printing. I started with ordinary ABS (100 % filling) and see the following issue with the tool. After a couple of dozens of drilling, the main holes become elliptic which leads to worse precision. I am not sure about the reason:

- Sometimes, I see plastic chips, but quite rare.
- I think that the drilling friction can make the material more flexible due to a raising of temperature, leading to the deformation of the holes while they are hot and under mechanical pressure.

I believe that this issue can be solved by choosing the proper material to produce the tool. Unfortunately, I've failed to find a good answer by Googling it on my own.

What would be a general recommendation for choosing material for such kinds of tools?

[image: Computer generated image of tool jig]

Comment: there is one more thing to consider depending on depth:diameter of holes- drill bit attachments.  A couple of collars on the bit turned down to be concentric can give a friendlier, and better aligned surface for contact than the flutes of the bit itself.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any 3D printed plastic is suitable for this. You should consider using a (drill/jig) bushing. This is a metal piece that can be inserted into your 3D print to provide a more durable surface for your drill bit to be guided by. [Here's an example](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/fk8rkj/hole_drilling_jig_using_brass_bushing/) of a bushing used with a 3D printed part.